# Finding PMF from CDF results in a 0 constant

Tags: probability

I have a CDF $\  F(x)= \frac {x+1}{k} $ for $\ -1 \leq x \leq 1 $

Asked to find the pdf results in $\ f(x) =  \frac {1}{k} $

Then asked to find the value of the constant k leads me to re-integrate:

$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac {1}{k} \text{ d}x $

$\int_{0}^{1}\frac {x}{k} \text{ d}x + \int_{-1}^{0}\frac {x}{k} \text{ d}x $

$\ [ \frac{1}{k}  + 0] + [0 + \frac{-1}{k}] = 1$

Which results in k =0. Naturally I am suspicious.

Can anyone verify these steps?

Comment: Your (wrong) result does not imply  that $k=0$. Since the integral would be always 1, k could be everything except 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You computed the integral incorrectly.
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{k} \mathop{dx} = \frac{1}{k} \int_{-1}^1  1\mathop{ dx} = \frac{2}{k},$$
so $k=2$.

You could actually get the value of $k$ directly from the CDF, from the property that $F(x) \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$. (In particular, you need $F(1)=1$.)